# How do I access various Outlook folders through Python using win32.client

Tags: python, email, winapi, outlook, directory

I intend on parsing my entire email inbox for those emails with the subject 'production' in order to extract the email into a .txt file for further parsing. I have successfully got Python to locate every email in my inbox as I have created counts which show the number of emails and the related emails (total emails and emails with subject 'production'). I want to know if through Python, I can move emails between Outlook folders, so from Inbox to a folder named 'production' within Outlook. My current code looks like (contains a GUI in to successfully meet the requirements of my coursework):

```
from tkinter import *
import win32com.client
import sys
import os.path
save_path = 'D:/Test1/'
nGui=Tk() 
title=nGui.title('Production Accolation')
geo=nGui.geometry
def homepage():
    geo('250x150')
    title
    BtnSta=Button(text="Start", command=start,height=2,width=100,font = "Calibri 12 bold").pack()
    BtnRep=Button(text="Report",command=report,height=2, width=100,font = "Calibri 12 bold").pack()
    BtnExi=Button(text="Exit",fg="red",command=end, height=2,width=100,font = "Calibri 12 bold").pack()
    nGui.mainloop()
def start():
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    messages = inbox.Items
    message = messages.GetLast()
    subject=message.Subject
    emailcount=0
    corrcount=0
    misccount=0
    for m in messages:
        emailcount=emailcount+1
        if m.Subject=="production":

             corrcount=corrcount+1
             email="outlookparse"
             compemail=os.path.join(save_path, email+".txt")
             file1=open(compemail,"w")
             file1.write(message.body)
             file1.close()
         else:
             misccount=misccount+1
     print("Total Emails ",emailcount)
     print("Production Emails ",corrcount)
     print("Miscellaneous Emails ",misccount)
def report():
    print("ok")
def end():
    exit()
homepage()
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is the folder located? If it is subfolder of the Inbox, use `inbox.Folders.Item("production").`

Comment: Yes it is, that was the folder I was looking for, thanks. But, is there a way of moving emails in the inbox to that folder completely inside outlook??

Comment: Sure, call MailItem.Move passing the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the file with this snippet: `file1.write(m.body)`